# How to strip down the string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, substring

I have a really long string, I just want to extract some certain string inside that string. How can I do that?

for example I have:

```
this is the image <img src="http://vnexpress.net/Files/Subject/3b/bd/67/6f/chungkhoan-xanhdiem2.jpg"> and it is very beautiful.
```

and yes now i want to get substring this long string and get only `http://vnexpress.net/Files/Subject/3b/bd/67/6f/chungkhoan-xanhdiem2.jpg`

Please show me how I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
NSRegularExpression* regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"src=\"([^\"]*)\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSString *text = @"this is the image <img src=\"http://vnexpress.net/Files/Subject/3b/bd/67/6f/chungkhoan-xanhdiem2.jpg\"> and it is very beautiful.";
NSArray *imgs = [regex matchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
if (imgs.count != 0) {
    NSTextCheckingResult* r = [imgs objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", [text substringWithRange:[r rangeAtIndex:1]]);
}
```

This regular expression is the heart of the solution:

```
src="([^"]*)"
```

It matches the content of the `src` attribute, and captures the content between the quotes (note a pair of parentheses). This caption is then retrieved in `[r rangeAtIndex:1]`, and used to extract the part of the string that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regular expression, probably using the [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Here's an example that does exactly what you want (from [here](http://remarkablepixels.com/blog/2011/1/13/regular-expressions-on-ios-nsregularexpression.html)):

```
- (NSString *)stripOutHttp:(NSString *)httpLine
{
    // Setup an NSError object to catch any failures
    NSError *error = NULL;  
    // create the NSRegularExpression object and initialize it with a pattern
    // the pattern will match any http or https url, with option case insensitive
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
        regularExpressionWithPattern:@"https?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)?" 
                             options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                               error:&error];
    // create an NSRange object using our regex object for the first match in the string httpline
    NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:httpLine
                                                         options:0
                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [httpLine length])];
    // check that our NSRange object is not equal to range of NSNotFound
    if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)))
    {
        // Since we know that we found a match, get the substring from the parent
        // string by using our NSRange object
        NSString *substringForFirstMatch = [httpLine substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];
        NSLog(@"Extracted URL: %@",substringForFirstMatch);
        // return the matching string
        return substringForFirstMatch;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlString = nil;
NSString *htmlString = //Your string;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:htmlString];

[scanner scanUpToString:@"<img" intoString:nil];
if (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"http" intoString:nil];
    NSCharacterSet *charset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@">"];
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:&urlString];
}
NSLog(@"%@", urlString);
```